# Multiplication of large sparse matrices causes memory error

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix, multiplication

I have a large simple graph `G`, which has about 100k node, and its adjacency matrix `A` (sparse, symmetric and binary). I need to calculate `(A*A).A`, but unfortunately `A*A` causes memory error in MATLAB. Is there any efficient way to do that?

Note: I tried with sparse matrix format.

Comment: What is `nnz(A)`? Is it a directed graph (i.e. is it symmetric)?

Comment: thanks for your comment,yes, as i said above it is sparse and symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: I'm assuming `nnz(A)` is fairly low. I just tested this with `nnz(A) = 9999963`, and `size(A) = 1000000x1000000`. The intuitive approach is to work with the data in "chunks". Take the first 10000 columns (all rows) and the first 10000 rows (all columns), the next 10000, the next etc. I believe this should avoid the memory problems.

I've just tested `A*A`, and got the same memory problems as you did. What I did was, convert `A` to logical: `A_logical = logical(A)`. This reduces the size of your matrix quite a bit. Note, you can't use `uint8` or something similar, since the only datatypes supported by `sparse` are `logical` and `double`.

Now, `A_logical*A_logical` fails with the error message:

> ```
> Error using  * 
> Both logical inputs must be scalar.
> ```

However, squaring a logical matrix works fine:

```
A_square = A_logical^2;
```

Note, the result of the `A_logical^2` is not a logical matrix, but a double, so you will get the correct values, not only `1` and `0`.

This worked fine for me with no memory problems. The computer halted for about 20 seconds, so it's a "tough" computation, but it worked.

Comment: Strange that `A_logical*A_logical` and `A_logical^2` show different behaviors... Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I think so too. I guess it has to do with `A_logical*B_logical` being a computation that's not implemented in MATLAB because it's more complex than just squaring (the two matrices can for instance have different sizes).  `A_logical^2` is guaranteed to be two square matrices with the same dimensions, thus simpler to implement.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately the memory problem still exists for me. can you explain how to do the multiplication in chunks?

Comment: Have a look at the bottom of [this website](http://www.math.nyu.edu/~neylon/linalgfall04/project1/jme/index). Also, what's `nnz(A)`?

Comment: OK, i will, 'nnz(A)=5899882'

Comment: @RezaSh, hmm... My computer is slow and 4 years old, and I had no problems with almost twice as many non-zero elements, and no symmetry...